# Installing openstack on mac

Tags: macos, openstack

I am unable to find how to install openstack on my macbook.

I tried googling but every where i am getting for ubuntu and not for mac
Kindly help me to install as i am a noob in openstack

Answer (score 3):

Late reply but just in case:

You can install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and get ubuntu running on it. Directly installing OpenStack on your macbook is usually a bad thing to do since it can mess up your system.

Answer (score 3):

Very late answer but this is to install the openstack command line clients.

first, you have to have python installed on your machine. Open the terminal and type `python --version`. If you see something like `Python 2.7.9`, go to next step.

So now, you have to install pip. Pip is a python package manager. You do this by typing `easy_install pip`. Should work.

Then you have to install every clients one by one.

(taken straight from http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/common/cli_install_openstack_command_line_clients.html)

```
ceilometer - Telemetry API
cinder - Block Storage API and extensions
glance - Image service API
heat - Orchestration API
neutron - Networking API
nova - Compute API and extensions
sahara - Database Processing API
swift - Object Storage API
trove - Database service API
openstack - Common OpenStack client supporting multiple services
```

And the way to install those, one by one, is by calling:
`pip install python-PROJECTclient`.

So, for instance, you go `pip install python-openstackclient`. Or `pip install python-novaclient`. You do that for every client that you need.

Don't forget, before you be able to use those APIs, you have to set up particular environment variables in your shell by sourcing an "openrc" file: http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/common/cli_set_environment_variables_using_openstack_rc.html

Once this is done, you may use the clients API.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like progress has been made since these last posts.  The easiest answer for just testing out OpenStack on your local machine is to use devstack.

Tutorial:
http://anteaya.info/blog/2013/09/01/installing-devstack-with-vagrant/

NOTE: The tutorial mentions to `mv samples/localrc .` but the file name has been updated to local.conf.  Also, I copied the file over instead of moving it.

DevStack Homepage:
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/

Answer (score 0):

You can install Openstack's python-client which is tools for sending command via http.

But there is no official option to install Openstack services on mac, yet. You can use Hypervisor like Virtualbox and Vmware to install Linux and launch Openstack Services, or docker.